# Matcher's matches() method returns false, find() and groupCount() return results

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code:

```
private static final String ET_AL = "(\\p{Punct}|\\b|^|\\s)et\\.? al\\.?(\\b|$|\\s)";
private static final Pattern ET_AL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(ET_AL, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

...

```
Matcher m = ET_AL_PATTERN.matcher("Doe, J.; Brown, C.; et al");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
m.reset();
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

The loop prints "et al" but the call to m.matches() returns false. Also m.groupCount() returns 2. Any help about what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but the call to m.matches() returns false.

It is because [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) requires you to match complete input with your regex.

From Javadoc:

> **public boolean matches()**
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern. If the match
>   succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and
>   group methods.

Comment: Ah, I see what I did. Or more accurately what I did not do. Thanks. I'm adding .* to the beginning and end of the pattern.

Comment: Yes that should definitely help.

Comment: I also found that m.find() does what I want for the original regular expression . . . there are subtle differences between find(), lookingAt(), and matches(). At least...subtle to me! But now I learned something new which is always good.